# Javascript switch case with multiple expression

Tags: javascript, react-native

I currently attempted to write a switch case taking in 3 variables

```
switch (user.nameInDB === userInputMobile,
        user.phoneInDB === userNumberInputMobile,
        user.emailInDB === userInputFrontend) {
   case ( true, _, _) :
      // Do something
   case ( _, true, _) :
      // Do something else
   case ( _, _, true) :
      // Do last thing
   default:
     break;
   }
```

I have ran into an error where the " _ " is not defined. Any advise on how to organise this?

[image]

Comment: Well `_` just isn’t defined... maybe you wanted to put `undefined` rather than `_`

Comment: [Here's the documentation for `switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). `switch` is unsuitable for your purposes.

Comment: @MrMythical In this example yes, you are correct. However.. it is not undefined. If it were... it would result in false as well.

Comment: @Andy Thank you, yes I have read that before, any other suggestions if you think it's not suitable?

Comment: However it can’t be defined since there is a ReferenceError. It may have been defined in a different scope

Comment: @MrMythical not by react native error message, it just mentions "Uncaught error, _ is not defined" and points to one of the case's underscore.

Comment: Is it a `ReferenceError`? Usually it won’t just say `Uncaught Error`

Comment: @MrMythical how would you go about checking?

Comment: It would be in the exact error logged - what is the exact error?

Comment: Added additional info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only checking for one variable at a time or maybe even more I recommend using If statments instead, It improves code readability and also has better performance than checking for multiple variables that aren't required to checked.

```
if (user.nameInDB === userInputMobile) {
   // do something
}
```

However, If you wish to use switch statments you could just pass `undefined`,  `null` or `true/false` depending on your use case.

Comment: unfortunate, it's not like other OOP language... we can do multiple checks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), `switch` statement evaluates an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators). So what you are trying to achieve

```
switch (expression1, expression2, expression3, ...)
```

Is the wrong way.

If you want to use `switch` for the same thing, you can use

```
const _ = false
const expression = [true, false, false].join()

switch(expression){
   case [true, _, _].join(): 
   // Do something
   case [_, true, _].join(): 
   // Do something
   case [_, _, true].join(): 
   // Do something
   default: 
   // Do something
}
```